# How to make a chrome extension that opens of it's popup?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a chrome extension that contains "folders" of links, similar to a bookmark folder on chrome. These open on hover. The issue I am having is that the tooltip is unable to be seen without artificially extending the size of the div created when clicking the icon, and it just does not look right.

To simplify; is it possible to create something similar to the menus within chromes settings, without removing functionality.

Comment: A screenshot might help; as a new user, you will only be able to post a link, but we can edit it to be an image.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Usually, including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: No, you will have to display everything inside.